# How do I see current Slowly Changing Dimension settings?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm looking at an SSIS package that includes Slowly Changing Dimensions.  I want to see what was previously selected, but when I go to Edit, the Slowly Changing Dimension Wizard pops up as if I'm starting from scratch.  How do I see what the current settings for the Slowly Changing Dimension are?

Thank you.

Comment: This component is a "one way wizard". You enter values and it creates components from that. It is actually a terrible idea and I actively discourage its use. You could crack open the various components that it generates to try and reverse engineer it if you like.

Comment: Ok, understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to see the current settings of an SCD Component, that can be done.
Select the SCD Component and choose ***Show Advanced Editor...*** in context menu. You will be presented with current SCD component settings like Connection Managers (on the first tab),

[image: Component properties tab]

Some settings related to inferred members and the SQL Command which defines your SCD destination.
Column Mappings tab can help with column mapping between incoming data flow and destination columns.
Input and Output properties tab defines functions of incoming columns. For example,

[image: Input and Output tab 1]

for `end_date` column its function is **Changing Attribute**, and for

[image: Input and Output tab 2]

the column `id` its function is the **Key**.
More information about SCD Component settings is in [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/transformation-custom-properties?view=sql-server-ver15#scd).

Theoretically, you can alter SCD component settings from this Advanced Editor, but in the most cases it is not practical. As being said, SCD Component Editor is more a wizard, which configures SCD Component itself and dependent components on the flow. Altering settings of the SCD Component via **Advanced Editor** can easily invalidate following components on the Data Flow.